# How to convert a constant value of php code input in to html tags forms

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

```
<?php

function convert_number($number) {
    if (($number < 0) || ($number > 999)) {
        echo ("Number is out of range");
    } else if (!is_numeric($number)) {
        echo ("not a number");
    } else {
        $Hn = floor($number / 100);
        $number -= $Hn * 100;
        $Dn = floor($number / 10);
        $n = $number % 10;
        $res = "";
        if ($Hn) {
            $res .= (empty($res) ? "" : " ") .
                    convert_number($Hn) . " Hundred";
        }
        $ones = array("", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
            "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen",
            "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eightteen",
            "Nineteen");
        $tens = array("", "", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Fourty", "Fifty", "Sixty",
            "Seventy", "Eigthy", "Ninety");
        if ($Dn || $n) {
            if (!empty($res)) {
                $res .= " and ";
            }
            if ($Dn < 2) {
                $res .= $ones[$Dn * 10 + $n];
            } else {
                $res .= $tens[$Dn];
                if ($n) {
                    $res .= "-" . $ones[$n];
                }
            }
        }
        if (empty($res)) {
            $res = "zero";
        }
        return $res;
    }
}

$cheque_amt = "342";
?>
<form method="post">
   Input in Numbers:
   <input type="text" name="res" value="<?php echo $cheque_amt ?>">
   <br>
   <br>
   Output in words:
   <input type="text" name="lname" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo convert_number($cheque_amt) ?>">
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. WHat is your exact problem with your code?

Comment: Does your code work? Is there something not happening that you want to have happen?

Comment: Rather than writting this complex code, use PHP's existing class: http://dk2.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

Comment: @AliZia - why would you waste time formatting spacing and brackets? It is completely ok to have different formatting than you prefer.

Comment: @mplungjan, I'm sorry mate. I won't do it again.

Answer (score 1):

Why use PHP at all?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("calc").onsubmit = function() {
    this.num2.value = convert_number(this.num1.value);
    return false;
  }
}


function convert_number($number) {
  if (isNaN($number) || $number < 0 || $number > 999) {
    return "Number is out of range";
  }
  var $Hn = Math.floor($number / 100);
  $number -= $Hn * 100;
  var $Dn = Math.floor($number / 10);
  var $n = $number % 10;
  var $res = "";
  if ($Hn) {
    $res += ($res == "" ? "" : " ") + convert_number($Hn) + " Hundred";
  }
  var $ones = ["", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
    "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen",
    "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eightteen",
    "Nineteen"
  ];
  var $tens = ["", "", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Fourty", "Fifty", "Sixty",
    "Seventy", "Eigthy", "Ninety"
  ];
  if ($Dn || $n) {
    if ($res != "") {
      $res += " and ";
    }
    if ($Dn < 2) {
      $res += $ones[$Dn * 10 + $n];
    } else {
      $res += $tens[$Dn];
      if ($n) {
        $res += "-" + $ones[$n];
      }
    }
  }
  return $res == "" ? "zero" : $res;
}
```

```html
<form id="calc">
  Input in Numbers:
  <input type="text" name="num1" value="">
  <br>
  <br>Output in words:
  <input type="text" name="num2" readonly="readonly" value="">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create function like this .

```
function convert_number_to_words($number) {

        $hyphen      = '-';
        $conjunction = ' and ';
        $separator   = ', ';
        $negative    = 'negative ';
        $decimal     = ' point ';
        $dictionary  = array(
            0                   => 'zero',
            1                   => 'one',
            2                   => 'two',
            3                   => 'three',
            4                   => 'four',
            5                   => 'five',
            6                   => 'six',
            7                   => 'seven',
            8                   => 'eight',
            9                   => 'nine',
            10                  => 'ten',
            11                  => 'eleven',
            12                  => 'twelve',
            13                  => 'thirteen',
            14                  => 'fourteen',
            15                  => 'fifteen',
            16                  => 'sixteen',
            17                  => 'seventeen',
            18                  => 'eighteen',
            19                  => 'nineteen',
            20                  => 'twenty',
            30                  => 'thirty',
            40                  => 'fourty',
            50                  => 'fifty',
            60                  => 'sixty',
            70                  => 'seventy',
            80                  => 'eighty',
            90                  => 'ninety',
            100                 => 'hundred',
            1000                => 'thousand',
            1000000             => 'million',
            1000000000          => 'billion',
            1000000000000       => 'trillion',
            1000000000000000    => 'quadrillion',
            1000000000000000000 => 'quintillion'
        );

        if (!is_numeric($number)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (($number >= 0 && (int) $number < 0) || (int) $number < 0 - PHP_INT_MAX) {
            // overflow
            trigger_error(
                'convert_number_to_words only accepts numbers between -' . PHP_INT_MAX . ' and ' . PHP_INT_MAX,
                E_USER_WARNING
            );
            return false;
        }

        if ($number < 0) {
            return $negative . convert_number_to_words(abs($number));
        }

        $string = $fraction = null;

        if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
            list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
        }

        switch (true) {
            case $number < 21:
                $string = $dictionary[$number];
                break;
            case $number < 100:
                $tens   = ((int) ($number / 10)) * 10;
                $units  = $number % 10;
                $string = $dictionary[$tens];
                if ($units) {
                    $string .= $hyphen . $dictionary[$units];
                }
                break;
            case $number < 1000:
                $hundreds  = $number / 100;
                $remainder = $number % 100;
                $string = $dictionary[$hundreds] . ' ' . $dictionary[100];
                if ($remainder) {
                    $string .= $conjunction . convert_number_to_words($remainder);
                }
                break;
            default:
                $baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));
                $numBaseUnits = (int) ($number / $baseUnit);
                $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
                $string = convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit];
                if ($remainder) {
                    $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
                    $string .= convert_number_to_words($remainder);
                }
                break;
        }

        if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
            $string .= $decimal;
            $words = array();
            foreach (str_split((string) $fraction) as $number) {
                $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
            }
            $string .= implode(' ', $words);
        }

        return $string;
    }
```